# Relation beween safe steering angle and velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

Assuming a car to be a point mass moving along a curve, what be a simplistic relation between the steering angle and velocity of a car so that it stays on track, i.e. the prescribed radius? I am trying to come up with a simple linear equation, even if valid for a small range of steering angle.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solved problem in the field of *vehicle dynamics*, as follows.

First you determine whether you want the car to *understeer* upon reaching its traction limit (where you begin to skid in a turn) or *oversteer* or *slide*. Understeering is where the front wheels break traction with the road before the rear wheels do, which causes the car to stop turning and go into the ditch in a straight line. Oversteering is when the rear wheels break traction first, which causes the rear end of the car to stop tracking in the turn and swing out, sharpening the turn and causing a *spinout*. A slide is when the front and rear wheels break free at the same time, causing the car to continue turning but at an increased turn radius.

Then, knowing the weight distribution (front-to-rear) and the speed at which you wish to safely make the turn, you then choose the tire contact area with the road which furnishes the correct amount of frictional force to turn the car without exceeding the critical static-to-dynamic friction transition point, taking into account whether you want understeer, oversteer, or slide dynamics.

Most passenger cars sold to the general public are designed to gradually understeer in a too-sharp turn. Sports cars are designed to slide, and incompetently-designed cars (rear-engined Chevrolet Corvairs from the 1960's, for example) will oversteer (which is dangerous!).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see my edited post. I am essentially looking for the very simplistic case of this scenario. I know it sounds trivial, a simple direction in which I can look it up myself would be also be very helpful.

Comment: try posting this on the engineering stack exchange instead. -NN